# htaccess rewriterule not working properly

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule books/(.*)/(.*) php/booksByLanguage.php?lid=$2 
RewriteRule list_books/(.*)/(.*) php/listBooks.php?cat_id=$2
```

I am using htaccess to rewrite url (above is the code i am using)

the problem is the second line ( `RewriteRule list_books/(.*)/(.*) php/listBooks.php?cat_id=$2`) is not working properly. ie,

the second line will work properly when i comment the first line (`RewriteRule books/(.*)/(.*) php/booksByLanguage.php?lid=$2` )

The following code works fine

```
 RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule books/(.*)/(.*) php/booksByLanguage.php?lid=$2 
    RewriteRule list_books/(.*)/(.*) php/listBooks.php?cat_id=$2
```

I want both rule to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding start and end markers ^  $.

> RewriteRule ^/books/(.*)/(.*)$
>   php/booksByLanguage.php?lid=$2

That way your first rule wont be triggered for list_books matches.

Comment: +1 recognised the problem correctly, -1 solution will probably not work because of site structure,
+1 for effoert. sum: +1

Comment: :) I appreciate the clarification of your three clicks. I suspect though that this will get praveenmon over the hump for this particular issue.

Comment: Thank you guys, captain your answer worked for me. @joe i dont understand what u said, i am new here. any way, i marked this answer as accepted and made "this answer is useful" to 2.

Answer (score 2):

problem is: you didnt define the line beginning with ^.
so the first rule will always be matched, if the second one is matched too.
because it only needs to match the string. example:

`books.*` will match `booksshelf` as well as `mybookshelf`
 `^books.*` will only match `bookshelf`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule list_books/(.+)/(.+)$ php/listBooks.php?cat_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule books/(.+)/(.+)$ php/booksByLanguage.php?lid=$2
```

this should work but is not pretty.
thing is that when the first rule (in the updated code) is matched, the second will too. but not the other way round.

so i put it up and set the last switch `[L]` so that no other rule is executed afterwards.

this is however the WRONG way to go!

you should define your rewrite rules so that they match only what you want!

i don't know about your structure, so this might not work, but i can imagine something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/list_books/(.+)/(.+)$ php/listBooks.php?cat_id=$2
RewriteRule ^/books/(.+)/(.+)$ php/booksByLanguage.php?lid=$2
```

if this is your root level you need to include the beginning slash, as its part of the request but i cant tell you that without knowing your structure.

Comment: joe ur answer is also right. thank u very much. Ur detailed answer is just great. one more question how i can close this question .i cant see any close button here.

Comment: your questin is "closed" by accepting an answer. closing questions works only by several votes from members with enough reputation and is only meant for bad or unuseful questions.